# How to find duplicates within a group - SQL 2008

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have a table (MyTable) with following data.  (Order by Order_No,Category,Type)

```
Order _No   Category    Type    
Ord1    A   Main Unit   
Ord1    A   Other   
Ord1    A   Other   
Ord2    B   Main Unit   
Ord2    B   Main Unit   
Ord2    B   Other
```

What I need to do is, to scan through the table and see if any ‘Category’ has more than one ‘Main Unit’.
If so, give a warning for the whole Category.  Expected results should look like this.

```
Order _No   Category    Type      Warning
Ord1    A   Main Unit   
Ord1    A   Other   
Ord1    A   Other   
Ord2    B   Main Unit     More than one Main Units
Ord2    B   Main Unit     More than one Main Units
Ord2    B   Other     More than one Main Units
```

I tried couple of ways (using subquery) to achieve results, but no luck.  Please Help !!

```
(Case
 When (Select t1.Category
             From MyTable as t1 
    Where  MyTable.Order_No = t1.Order_No
                    AND MyTable.Category = t1. Category
        AND  MyTable.Type = t1.Type
               AND  MyTable.Type = ‘Main Unit’
    Group by t1. t1.Order_No, t1. Category, t1.Type
Having  Count(*) >1) = 1
Then ‘More than one Main Units’
Else ‘’ End ) as Warning
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be using `COUNT() OVER()`to count the main units, partitioning by category;

```
SELECT Order_No, Category, Type, 
  CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN Type='Main Unit' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) 
            OVER (PARTITION BY Category) > 1 
       THEN 'More than one Main Units' ELSE '' END Warning
FROM MyTable
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/69f0e/2).

Comment: It works  Joachim.  Thanks a lot  YOU made my day.  Have a Happy 2014 !!

Answer (score 0):

do you need to list all records?

If you only need the duplicates you could do something like this:

```
select Order_No, Category, Type, count(*) as dupes
from MyTable
where Type='Main Unit'
group by Order_No, Category, Type
having count(*)>1
order by count(*) DESC;
```

Comment: I went for the first one.. but Thank you for all the help

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the CTE. Here is the [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/495a9/1) for this

```
   ;with categoriesWithMoreThanOneType as
   (
      select category, order_type
      from
        mytable
      where 
        order_type = 'Main Unit'
      group by category, order_type
      having count(1) > 1
   )

   select
     m.*, 
     case 
       when c.order_type is null then ''
       else
        'More than one ' + c.order_type 
     end as Warning
   from 
      mytable m 
      left outer join categoriesWithMoreThanOneType c on 
         m.category = c.category
```

Comment: I went for the first one.. but Thank you for all the help

Answer (score 0):

just another option, using `EXISTS`

```
select [Order], _No, Category, Type, 
    (case when exists (
        select 1 from mytable t2
        Where category = 'main unit'
        and t2.[Order] = t.[Order] and t2._No = t._No
        group by [Order]
        having Count(*) > 1)
     then 'More than one Main Units'
     else '' end) as Warning
From MyTable t
```

[image]

Comment: I tried and this works too !  Thanks a lot. Learning something everyday thanks to people like YOU..